# How to make requests more polite in German?

Tags: question, politeness

For example,

How can I say these two sentences in a more polite way?

> 1."Can I kindly ask your support/help?"
>
> 2."Can you please support us on this topic?"

Comment: Hi, your question provides no context (it is a difference, whether a door should be kept open or your are moving and need some more pairs of hands) and does not suggest a translation with some specific doubts. Looking at [help section](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I consider it as off-topic.

Comment: "Dürfte ich freundlich um Unterstützung/Hilfe bitten? - Könnten Sie uns bitte bei diesem Thema unterstützen?" Are these correct? I have some ideas, but they are not certain for me. Therefore, I wouldn't want to redirect comments.

Comment: Why do you think the online translator of your choice is wrong?

Comment: Because I have never encountered such a use on the Internet.

Comment: @guidot I think, we should take into account that Ken Ru is quite new to the site. Imho, it would be more welcoming to give constructive advice. For instance _Do you have a certain context in mind? I am asking because the answer will be depending heavily on the context._ is more constructive then _your question provides no context [...] I consider it as off-topic_, although it addresses the same problem of the question.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach thank you for your kindness. I'll pay attention to what you said in the my next post.

Comment: What is your own attempt? This is not a translation service. Show some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing here in German is, while you can always add 'nice' words like "please", "Kindly" etc, there is an entirely different way to conjugate verbs such that they sound more polite. This is known as Konjunktiv zwei.

I have found this video from Easy German to be a [good primer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggZnDWlMBJ8) on this topic, you can also check out the Early exercises of duolingo, also [this website](https://www.gymglish.com/en/wunderbla/german-grammar/forming-and-using-the-konjunktiv-ii) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

*Darf ich Sie um Ihre Unterstützung bitten?*

and:

*Können Sie uns bitte bei diesem Thema unterstützen?*